# Azure SQL Standard Geo Replication & Disaster recovery

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

i'm configuring Standard Geo Replication for our Azure SQL database and need to validate Disaster recovery, but still have couple doubts and cannot find more details:)

1. I configured Standard Geo Replication and added Secondary database.
2. If i want to do DR Drill, i can just stop replication, make the second database as primary and re-point my ASP.NET applications to the new database server. Just change SQL server name.

My questions are:

1. What if Microsoft has some issues with data center, do they automatically just re-points DNS from main SQL to secondary so i don't need to do anything, and it would be done silently and everything would work, without my change?
2. I was trying to find out, if there is some kind of notification, that i can configure if SQL has an issue and i can stop replication and do this process by myself. Or will microsoft somehow notify us? email,... or only SQL AZURE dashboard?
3. What could be the case, that i need to do DR manually? Main SQL would stop working and AZURE cannot take care of that because...?

thanks a lot for your answers
Rado

Comment: Did you figure out your answers?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issues recently, we did not receive any email's or notification. 
Luckily only SQL-Azure was affected. Hence we stopped the replication and updated connection string to point to secondary.

- No they do not automatically re-point DNS from primary to secondary for databases
- We have external services that keeps track of our systems and notifies us when things are not right.
- We had to do a manual DR.

Would love to know if any one has a workflow in place to automate it or point to the right direction.

Hope that helps.